# SSL/TLS is not working with .p7b certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate2, tls1.2

I generated the client certificate from some payment provider and I have to use it in request to theirs https API. My code looks like:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://site/api/requests/");

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.ContentLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(postDataSerialized);
request.KeepAlive = false;

request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
certCollection.Import(@"d:\Production Merchant Certificate.p7b");

request.ClientCertificates.AddRange(certCollection);
request.PreAuthenticate = true;


using (StreamWriter os = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream())) //Exception
{
}
```

And I always get two errors:

> Error occured while sending POST (Form) request The underlying
>   connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
>   System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport
>   connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
>   host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection
>   was forcibly closed by the remote host.

and

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

I would be grateful if you could tell me what is the proper way to send a request with a chain of certificates.

In Microsoft Management Console I have added the p7b to Personal and Intermediate Certification Authorities for Local Computer, and still I get these two errors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your client certificates do not contain private key at all. PKCS#7 container (with .p7b file extension) is not supposed to store certificates with private keys. You need to get certificate object with valid reference to private key. The certificate may be installed in your personal certificate store (CurrentUser\My), or by importing PKCS#12 (with .pfx or .p12 file extension) container which is supposed to store certificates with private keys.

Comment: But in the documentation I can read that: The response (PKCS#7 or PEM) will contain your client certificate and all CA certificates up to the Root.Import the generated certificate and all CA certificates to your server. 
From where I can get private key? .p12 file?

Comment: Certificates to the server are sent in PKCS#7. Without private keys. It is correct. However, leaf certificate must contain a private key in order to perform certificate-based authentication. For example, server will encrypt the session key by using your public key. How you suppose to decrypt the session key without private key?